# Hierarchical Metadata - how can they be used in search reasonably?

Tags: metadata, term-store, term-set

In a SharePoint 2013 site, we have defined metadata hierarchically in groups like a tree.

### My question:

Which behavior of SharePoint 2013 is possible and "wanted" for searching content by such metadata (see example below):

- If I tag a document with "Porsche 911", can it also be found when searching for **"column: car"**?
- If I have a general document about the history of the car and tag it with "cars", could it appear in search results if someone searches for "luxury" or "Bentley" or another child term of "cars"?

Both scenarios could make sense IMHO from the end user's perspective, but I think it might be confusing if they are not used consequently.

- Can both possible be implemented with `SharePoint 2013 (Standard)` without additional programming?
- Are there general guidelines for Termstore administrators who define the Taxonomy, what makes most sense?

It's definitely an important point, because on the one hand the people assigning metadata to documents must know under which circumstances their document will appear in search results later and on the other hand, the users searching for documents must understand the structure and intended use of metadata to find something.

### Hypothetical example for hiearchical metadata structure

[image]